# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate') onPress React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Working with react-native and I get a problem with navigator.

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import ItemListScreen from '../screens/ItemListScreen';
import ItemDetailsScreen from '../screens/ItemDetailsScreen';

export const RootStack = () => { 
    return createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: ItemList
        },

        ItemDetails: {
            screen: ItemDetails
        }
    }
)}

export const ItemList = createStackNavigator({
    ItemList: {
        screen: ItemListScreen
    }
},
{
    headerMode: 'none'
});

export const ItemDetails = createStackNavigator({
    ItemDetails: {
        screen: ItemDetailsScreen
    }
},
{
    headerMode: 'none'
});
```

**Header.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Header, Body, Text, Icon, Left, Right } from 'native-base';

export default class AppHeader extends Component {
    render() {
        const headerText = this.props.headerText
        return (
            <Header>
                <Left><Icon name='menu' onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} /></Left>
                <Body style={styles.header}>
                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>{headerText}</Text>
                </Body>
                <Right></Right>
            </Header>
        );
    }
}
```

**Index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Root, Button, Text, Drawer } from 'native-base';
import {RootStack} from './config/Routes';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import SideBar from './components/SideBar/SideBar';

export default class Index extends Component {

    render() {
        const Screen = RootStack();
        const { globalContainer } = styles;
        return (
            <Root style={ globalContainer }>
                <Header />
                <Screen />
            </Root>
        )
    }
}
```

The error is:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

The error is in OnPress() in Header.js

onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')

What is the cause of this error? How to solve?

Comment: are you sure header.js is called from index.js?  I cannot find any declaration of index.js in your navigator class

Comment: Are you able to access navigation prop from within the Index component ? If yes you can simply pass down the prop to child component. If not then probably you have not configured the navigation properly.

Comment: you can see I have used my Routes as const Screen = RootStack(); at my index.js file. @AseemUpadhyay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navigation object is not defined since you are not providing it the object.

You can include the `navigation` object using two ways,

1. Declare the object in the `StackNavigator` class
2. Pass `navigation` props explicitly. For example - in `index.js` you'll need to change `<Header />` to `<Header navigation={this.props.navigation} />`. So, here you are providing it the necessary proprs in order to execute the `navigate` action.

**EDIT**

The actual issue is here,

```
<Root style={ globalContainer }>
            <Header />
            <Screen />
        </Root>
```

you are defining your routes later, but calling your `Header` screen earlier. So precisely, `navigation` object is `undefined` in `index.js` itself.

What you should do is, list `index.js` in the `StackNavigator` class as the first object, so it'll be called first. So, your index.js will look something like this.

```
<Root style={ globalContainer }>
            <Header navigation={this.props.navigation} />   //navigation object will be defined here         
</Root>
```

Also, as i see, you have made your `DrawerNavigator` as your RootStack. I'll like to propose something different, You define a `StackNavigator` as your root stack, and then include drawer navigation in it.

Something on the lines of -

```
export const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
Index: //your index.js screen declaration
Drawer: //drawer navigator object
ItemDetails: {
    screen: ItemDetailsScreen
  }
},
```

**EDIT 2**

You'll be not be calling Rootstack in index.js. Your index.js will look something like this.

export default class Index extends Component {

```
render() {
    const { globalContainer } = styles;
    return (
        <Root style={ globalContainer }>
            <Header navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
        </Root>
    )
}
}
```

If index.js is your entry file, then you'll have to create a new entry file that calls the RootStack.

Something like entryFile.js

```
render() { return <RootStack /> }
```

which will automatically render all your routes and place index.js as your first screen.

Comment: Thanks I tried option 2 but still same. not sure how to do option 1. pls help

Comment: Yap, good catch. I have noticed so. Let me try your suggestion. Thanks a lot @Aseem

Comment: one more question, how to use RootStack() at index.js??

Comment: thanks, your suggestion helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue. My approach has been given below:

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Drawer } from './Drawer';    

export const App = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Drawer: {
            screen: Drawer
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Drawer",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
)
```

**Drawer.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import ItemListScreen from '../screens/ItemListScreen';
import SideBar from '../components/SideBar/SideBar';

export const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: ItemListScreen }
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: {
            gesturesEnabled: false
        },
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        drawerPosition: 'left',
        contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
    }
);
```

**Index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Text, Drawer } from 'native-base';
import { App } from './config/Routes';
import AppHeader from './components/Header/Header';

export default class Index extends Component {
    render() {
        const { globalContainer } = styles;
        return (
            <App style={ globalContainer } navigation={this.props.navigation}></App>
        )
    }
}
```

**Header.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Header, Body, Text, Icon, Left, Right } from 'native-base';

export default class AppHeader extends Component {
    render() {
        const {navigation, headerText} = this.props
        const {header, text, drawerIcon } = styles
        return (
            <Header>
                <Left>
                    <Icon  name='menu' style={drawerIcon} onPress={()=> navigation.openDrawer()} />
                </Left>
                <Body style={header}>
                    <Text style={text}>{headerText}</Text>
                </Body>
                <Right></Right>
            </Header>
        );
    }
}
```